# Unity3D TypeLoadException

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL database through Unity. I've added a reference to System.Data in visual studio but unity is throwing the following error:

> TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute' from assembly 'System.Data'.

I've googled how to solve this issue, or what it actually means, but I can't find anything.

Is anyone able to shed some light on this and what I should do to fix it?

Comment: get any error log files or anything along the line ?    "This event provides notification of uncaught exceptions. It allows the application to log information about the exception before the system default handler reports the exception to the user and terminates the application."

Comment: I am getting same error

Answer (score 2):

Unity is using mono, not .NET. Because `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute` is a class from the .NET-framework 4.5, Unity can't load this class. You need to tell Visual Studio, that is mustn't compile against .NET-framework 4.5, but instead, you need to specify version 3.5 in your project-settings.

Comment: "you need to specify version 3.5 in your project" THAAANKS